# Save file path to realm.io and assign image with AlamofireImage

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire

I have a view controller that takes a photo then segue to a second view controller to preview the captured image.
So here's the problem, how do I assign my image to my imageview with alamofireimage?
This is the path that I receive

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=16F4079E-38B2-4B7C-953A-22395A528B5D&ext=JPG
```

Can anyone suggest how can I make use of this?

My code is as follow

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image!, 0.8)
    let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage?.CGImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: compressedImage!.imageOrientation.rawValue)!, completionBlock: {
        (path:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        print("\(path)")

        self.previewImageView.af_setImageWithURL(path)

    })
```

[image: Mock]

The preview controller is not in the mock. But it's to be segue after snapping, and then upon confirmation go back to the collectionview controller

Answer (score 0):

**AlamofireImage** its method `setImageWithURL` which is used to load image from server asyn. But Hare you have Asset URL, Which image is already store in your device, so Doen't use above method of AlamofireImage.

Use the below Code to load image from ALAsset URL :

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image!, 0.8)
    let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage?.CGImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: compressedImage!.imageOrientation.rawValue)!, completionBlock: {
        (path:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        print("\(path)")

          assetLibrary.assetForURL(path, resultBlock: { (asset: ALAsset!) -> Void in  
                        if asset != nil {
                             var assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
                             var iref = assetRep.fullScreenImage().takeUnretainedValue()
                             var image =  UIImage(CGImage: iref)
                             self.previewImageView.image = image     
                         }

                      }, failureBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
                                println(error.localizedDescription)
                   })

    })
```

Comment: What if for the sake of consistency I prefer to use AlamofireImage? Cause in my collection view controller I use AlamofireImage to load the images to the collection items anyways

Comment: You don't want to use AlamofireImage's UIImageView extensions for this particular case. Instead, follow @Kirit's advice and just use the UIImageView directly. The AlamofireImage UIImageView extensions are designed to interact with remote images, not local ones. All the other parts of AlamofireImage can still be quite useful, but I'd avoid using the UIImageView extensions in this fashion.